# jquery all first children no matter depth

Tags: jquery, css

how to get with jquery only all the first children having a specific css class, no matter the depth of these Html Element(s) in the DOM tree?

Answer (score 5):

It's right there in the documentation: [`:first-child`](https://api.jquery.com/first-child-selector/):

> **Description:** Selects all elements that are the first child of their parent.

Demo:

```js
$('div:first-child').css({border: '1px solid'});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div>I am a first child</div>
  <div>I am a second child
    <div> I am a nested first child</div>
    <div> I am a nested second child</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div>Yet another div child of the body</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery, you can just target the classname and it will throw all instances into an array for you - regardless of depth.

For example:

```
var children = $('.childclass');
console.log(children.length)//returns "3".
$(children[1]) //returns the second "childclass" instance
$(children[1]).css('color', 'red'); //will give the 2nd instance of the childclass red text.
```

https://jsfiddle.net/z1djzo2n/

```
<div class="topclass">
  <div class="childclass">
      <div class="someotherclass"></div>
      <div class="childclass"></div>
   </div>
   <div class="childclass"></div>
</div>
```

Otherwise, if you want to target them individually without jQuery like that, you can use the :first-child selector.

Comment: `children[1]` returns a dom element...not jQuery object. Can't use `css()` on a dom element. Also `length` is a property not a function

Comment: You are correct - I forgot to wrap the return in a jQuery object. Updated my answer.

Comment: why do that? Can use `eq()` instead. Either way this doesn't do what OP is asking